# K8 cluster communications in insecure networks

Tags: security, kubernetes, networking

According to [Control Plane-Node Communication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/control-plane-node-communication/),

the only way to communicate securely in an insecure network would be API-kubelet communication using parameter or SSH; and the other way mentioned could not be used productively without risk. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

As I read it, it is possible to use use the `--kubelet-certificate-authority` flag to provide a root certificate bundle.

But this is a narrow use case, that you also could avoid in a production environment, perhaps?

> To verify this connection, use the --kubelet-certificate-authority flag to provide the apiserver with a root certificate bundle to use to verify the kubelet's serving certificate.

From [apiserver to kubelet docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/control-plane-node-communication/)